# Which maven plugin should I install for Eclipse Indigo

Tags: eclipse, maven

I 've to use Eclipse indigo because of some plugin dependencies.

Which maven plugin(m2e) should I use for Eclipse indigo as the one available in Eclipse Marketplace is for Juno/above.

Thank You

Comment: I dont understand the question? `Which maven plugin(m2e)` m2e is the name of the ecipse plugin for manven integration. Are you confused about which version you should install ?

Comment: @SaifAsif yes, exactly, which m2e plugin to install in Indigo as when I installed plugin available was for juno. I gave me error `Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'MyProject'.
Lorg/codehaus/plexus/archiver/jar/JarArchiver;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't remember if m2e was available for Indigo but here are the [old versions](http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_updatesite_and_gittags), maybe you can use the release date as a guide. Worst case you can use the [maven eclipse plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/). Keep in mind that for newer versions of eclipse you should indeed use m2e and not m-eclipse-p

Answer (score 0):

You will have to download a previous release of the plugin to make it work with Indigo.